# Two Limit questions

Tags: calculus, limits, factoring, fractions, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_\limits{x\to 4}\;\frac{x^2 - 16}{3x - 12} $$

Factoring doesn't help so I'm not sure what to do

Also,

$$\lim_\limits{ x\to -\infty}\;\frac{x^3 - 5x^2}{3x}$$

If you put a really big negative number in $x^3$ it will still be negative, so I'm not sure why the answer is $\infty$ and not $-\infty $???

Comment: Hi! Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to use MathJax

Comment: ok so one simple way to see it is negative, the $x^3$ term will dominate and is negative, but so is the denominator. Also when simplifying the expressions of a limit, you do not have to worry about negatives getting lost the way you would undefined points. Can you prove it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow4}\frac{x^2-16}{3x-12}=\lim_{x\rightarrow4}\frac{(x-4)(x+4)}{3(x-4)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow4}\frac{x+4}{3}=\frac{8}{3}.$$
Actually, if $x\rightarrow4$ then by the definition of the limit $x\neq4$.

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{x^3-5x^2}{3x}=\frac{1}{3}\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}x^2\left(1-\frac{5}{x}\right)=+\infty.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x^3-5x^2}{3x}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x^2-5x}{3}$$ since $x^2>0$ and $x^2$ grows more rapidly than $5x$,
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x^2-5x}{3}=\infty$$